# How to create arrays of positions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm pretty new to Javascript/Jquery and I don't really understand it. I'm currently working on an interactive quiz, and you need to click on a specific location to move on to the next question. I've figured out the position by finding the client-x.

I attempted to create the quiz by using an if then statement, but I'm not sure how to change the positions to move on to the next question. I'm guessing the best way would be by creating arrays of the positions.

I'd appreciate any insight I can get.

JS:

```js
// var positions = [[510, 650, 680, 768], [700, 930, 630, 768], [580, 630, 260, 320]];

function showCoords(evt) {

  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  console.log("X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y);

  var leftIndent = $("#pages")[0].offsetParent.offsetLeft;
  if ((evt.clientX > (510 + leftIndent) && evt.offsetX < (650 + leftIndent)) && (evt.clientY > 680 && evt.clientY < 768)) {
    console.log("answer is correct");
    $(".question > h3").text("Well Done! You found it.").delay("slow");
    $(".next-1").addClass("show");
    $('.next-1').click(function() {
      $("#cam-1").addClass("hide");
      $("#cam-2").addClass("show");
      $(".question > h3").text("Find The Camouflaged Animal In This Biome").delay("slow");


    });

  } else {
    console.log("answer is wrong");
    $(".question  > h3").text("Sorry, that's not it. Try again.").delay("slow");

  }

}
```

```html
<div id="page-camouflage" onclick="showCoords(event)" class="current">

  <img id="bubble" alt="speech" src="images/bubble.svg">
  <img class="cloud" alt="clouds floating in the sky" src="images/cloud.png">

  <div class="question">
    <h3> Find The Camouflaged Animal In This Biome </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="help">
    <img alt="help button" src="images/help.svg">
    <h2 id="hint">
      Frogs like chilling by the pond.
    </h2>
  </div>


  <div id="cam-1">

    <div class="hidden">
      <img id="frog" alt="frog" src="images/cam/frog.svg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img id="leaf" alt="leaf" src="images/cam/cam1.svg">
    </div>

    <audio id="croak">
      <source src="audio/frog.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element
      </audio>

    <div>
      <img class="next-1" alt="next button" src="images/next.svg">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="cam-2">
    <div>
      <img id="lion2" alt="lion" src="images/cam/lion.svg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img id="grass" alt="leaf" src="images/cam/grass.svg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="next-2" alt="next button" src="images/next.svg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="cam-3">
    <div>
      <img id="pigeon" alt="pigeon" src="images/cam/pig.svg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img id="tree" alt="tree" src="images/cam/tree.svg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img id="trash" alt="trash" src="images/cam/trash.svg">
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do with the positions, why not handle it all in click events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea, you just need to push it a bit further :

```
var positions = [[510, 650, 680, 768], [700, 930, 630, 768], [580, 630, 260, 320]];
var count = 0;

function showCoords(evt) {

 var x = event.clientX;
 var y = event.clientY;
 console.log("X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y);

 var leftIndent = $("#pages")[0].offsetParent.offsetLeft;
 if ((evt.clientX > (positions[count][0] + leftIndent) && evt.offsetX < (positions[count][1] + leftIndent)) && (evt.clientY > positions[count][2] && evt.clientY < positions[count][3])) {
  console.log("answer is correct");
  count++;
  $(".question > h3").text("Well Done! You found it.").delay("slow");
  $(".next-1").addClass("show");
  $('.next-1').click(function() {
   $("#cam-1").addClass("hide");
   $("#cam-2").addClass("show");
   $(".question > h3").text("Find The Camouflaged Animal In This Biome").delay("slow");
  });

 } else {
  console.log("answer is wrong");
  $(".question  > h3").text("Sorry, that's not it. Try again.").delay("slow");

 }

}
```

Here, the variable **count** keeps track of all the good answers.

In your **if**, I replaced everything by its equivalent in the **positions** array.

You can check if the user got them all by comparing count to the length of your positions array.

Comment: Thank you so much. That clears things up quite a bit. Really appreciate it.